# How to prepend a value to every property of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of paths for my API, and a way to prepend the hostname of the API to the urls, so that on API calls we can get the full URL.

```
export default {
  paths: {
    auth: {
      register: "/auth/register",
      login: "/auth/login",
    }
  },
  getUrl(path) {
    return API_HOST . path
  },
}
```

And to call this, we do:

`const url = ApiPaths.getUrl(ApiPaths.auth)`

Is there a more elegant way to call this? I saw that you can define a getter for each property using defineProperty, but that seems clunky. I'm open to an alternate solution as well if this isn't the best way to do this.

Comment: Which HTTP client library are you using to make requests?

Comment: I'm guessing what @ArunKumarMohan is getting at is, depending on the HTTP client library you use, you may be able to set the root context in the client instead of prepending it to all the paths.

Comment: @xdhmoore Exactly.

Comment: If the request has the same domain of the webpage you can just remove the initial `/`, something like  `register: "auth/register"`

Comment: Request does not have the domain as the webpage. We're using axios currently, and it does have the capability to set a baseUrl, which is a fine solution. I was more curious if javascript had a nice way to implement this in one place, to have one object be the definitive "this is the URL you want" for any call.